# Magento 2 Rest API For Android How to Create

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api

Magento 2 site How to create the REST API and how to send data with authenticates for mobile app.Please describe Step by Step.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below url for apis :

https://cyrillschumacher.com/2015/01/02/magento2---search-parameters-for-the-rest-api/

try with Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) , its very helpful to you.

if you want to create custom api than visit below url

https://www.aurigait.com/how-to-create-custom-api-in-magento-2/

Comment: Hello, Can you please tell me how to create api in magento 2 site admin panel with authentication

Comment: from admin panel we can't create api, we setup authentication. m2 provide apis which I shared (first)  url with you.

Comment: How to secure the data ?

Comment: anyone can using this url get the data

Comment: no, without authenticate and public key we can't

Comment: Can you Please describe me briefly with examples (no-links)

Comment: can you please explain, what you want ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95967/discussion-between-hardik-makwana-and-anas-mansuri).